# Lua: "Hide" functions

Tags: c, function, api, lua

I want to call c functions from lua to change variables defined in C, but I don't want the lua "user" to realize they are functions.

For example, consider an integer and an array created in c:

```
int c_level = 0;
int c_map[4] = {0,0,0,0};
```

Now the program creates a Lua state and runs this:

```
set_level(2) --c_level = 2
set_tile(1,23) --c_map[0] = 23
```

I want them to look like this in the lua script:

```
L_level = 2
L_map[1] = 23
```

So, **L_level** and **L_map** would be functions defined in C.

**L_level**'s argument would be "2".

**L_map**'s arguments are "1" and "23".

Is that possible?.

I can get the lua variables using getglobal, but I wanted to know if I can create some lua functions that look like the ones I showed.

Thanks.

Comment: You can accomplish that with light userdata, `__index` and `__newindex` metamethods.

Answer (score 1):

When you set

```
L_level = 2
```

you really index the global table `_G` with the key `L_level` and set it to `2`. What you can do is to set a *meta*-table for `_G` and set the function `__newindex` to a function, that checks if the key is `L_level` or `L_map` and handles these cases differently.

This function can be directly a C-function or a Lua-function, that checks the key and calls a c-function if the name matches one of your tracked names, for example like

```
setmetatable(_G, {
    __newindex = function (_, k, v)
        if (k == "L_level") then do_setlevel(v)
        elseif (k == "L_map") then do_setmap(v)
        else rawset(_G, k, v)
        endif
    end
})
```

`do_setlevel` and `do_setmap` are in this case global c functions. You can of course do all this completely in C, too.

Comment: I want to make everything in C, Thanks for the info :).

Comment: @Mills Well, you can adapt the method easily to C (`luaL_setmetatable()`, etc.)